# Why won't my raster image display with levelplot?

Tags: geospatial, raster, rasterizing, satellite

I am attempting to overlay a netcdf4 raster containing Aerosol Height data over Hawaii specifically. A sample file is available [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z15ag7f4uq090l8/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180715T201241_20180715T215609_03908_01_010301_20190530T173144.nc?dl=0) My variables of interest are latitude, longitude, time and aerosol height. Here is some reproducible data.

```
s1 <- data.frame(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat), as.vector(ah))
s1
#    as.vector.lon. as.vector.lat. as.vector.ah.
#1       -127.45199      -79.15431            NA
#2       -126.99632      -79.16919            NA
#3       -126.54577      -79.18321            NA
#4       -126.10027      -79.19641            NA
#5       -125.65974      -79.20880            NA
#6       -125.22412      -79.22042            NA
#7       -124.79333      -79.23129            NA

crsLatLon <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
ex <- extent(c(-180,180,-90,90))

#empty raster with 0.1 degree resolution
pmraster <- raster(ncol=360*10, nrow=180*10, crs=crsLatLon,ext=ex)

#fills the empty raster with values from dataframe, s1
pmraster <- rasterize(s1[,1:2], pmraster, s1[,3], fun=mean, na.rm=T)

show(pmraster)
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 1800, 3600, 6480000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source     : r_tmp_2020-06-26_114048_16840_75885.grd 
#names      : layer 
#values     : 0.1314196, 9424.118  (min, max)

#specifies region over Hawaii
exHI <- extent(c(-180,-140,10,30))

levelplot(crop(pmraster,exHI))

#Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
#In addition: Warning messages:
#1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Can anyone help explain why I am getting this error message and how I may proceed to produce the desired raster image? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should provide a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible, example*, either creating some data with code or using data that ships with an R package. Your question is about using levelplot with a Raster object, which can easily be done, but it is no easy to answer  without example data, and your question is full of code that we cannot run and that is irrelevant to problem at hand. Please edit your question.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, Robert. And thank you for your responsiveness to my R questions. I have modified the question to hopefully be more concise and provide some reproducible data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying this on different files, it became clear to me that there was no data available over the specific region I was isolating, resulting in my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal and reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
library(lattice)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
levelplot(r)
#Error in UseMethod("levelplot") : 
#  no applicable method for 'levelplot' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', #'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"
```

The `lattice` package methods do not know what a `Raster*` is. Hence you cannot use `levelplot` like this. The good news is that the `rasterVis` package implements a `lattice` method for `Raster*` objects; so all you need to do is

```
library(rasterVis)
levelplot(r)
```

And see `?rasterVis` for many more ways to use levelplot

`ssplot` is also built on levelplot

```
spplot(r)
```